# Java Game Server on website

Tags: java, web

If I were to have a website with a webhost like godaddy, how could I run a java program on that website as a server so that people can connect to the game with the address: www.whatever.com as opposed to an ip to connect to my pc?

Comment: Many web services like GoDaddy only allow for certain types of services, like HTTP. They may not allow arbitrary program execution, and if so, it may cost a *lot* more. So be prepared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your goal. You either have them give you a virtual or dedicated server that you can log in to the OS and create the application as an executable, or they allow java servlets.

You can read a little bit about servlets here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet

I know crappy, I posted a wikipedia entry...lol :) Cheers

EDIT:

I just saw the last part of your question and realized also what you are attempting. You need a virtual or actual server that you can log into the OS remotely. You need a DNS server for the domain name resolution. This can be provided by go daddy. I think you can get a virtual dedicated for like...30 a month or something? Depends how much performance you need.